# Either downloading images directly to SD card or moving to SD while retaining original time stamps?

Tags: external-sd

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 with 4.4.2. When I read manga online and save the images the files in a given sequence are generally in a 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. numbered format. When I copy these files from the DOWNLOAD folder to the SD card though it ends up arranging them like 1, 10, 2, etc. regardless of the file manager I use AND it changes the time stamps at the same time so that it's permanently stuck like that. At the worst, I had over 5k images get scrambled and I am NOT looking forward to sorting them out one at a time on a desktop computer.

I would like to avoid this problem in the future. I would either like to have them save to the SD card right away, or I would like to be able to have the files retain their original time stamp when moved to the SD card so that I can retain the order of viewing regardless of the name, or both. (Renaming one at a time to 001, 002, 003, etc isn't really an option.)

Note: After the update (which AT&T forced on me without my permission), I rooted my phone with towelroot and Superuser and edited permissions to regain the ability to copy without problems, so if there is a solution that requires a root I am ready for it.

Comment: You say "Renaming one at a time to 001, 002, 003, etc isn't really an option," but would you be happy with a solution that did that automatically?